# Using StyleGAN for generative design of aircraft

Tags: cnn, gan

I haven't worked on a machine learning project in a year and now that I am in university I am trying again :)

Anyway, the end goal is to create a GAN that can design aircraft. I was inspired by the [Czinger21c](https://www.czinger.com/about-21-c) because it was said that an AI generated the car. To me, this sounds like a GAN at work, but I personally have no experience working with GANs and I'm looking for a bit of guidance as well.

I've looked for a bit, and I saw a video about StyleGAN for faces. I was wondering if I can modify this for use with a parametric study; I want to have the GAN learn optimized aircraft and create its own.

I have experience working with CNNs, so I know I can do this, except I'm just working with two neural networks.

Thank you